# Android - Retrofit2 - Google app engine - Send image

Tags: android, google-app-engine, retrofit2

I can able to save data from mobile to GAE using retrofit2. I am trying to send image which is captured from camera, How to save image in google app engine using retrofit2. Is there any step by step process to make it work.

This is the code used to send data:

```
@OnClick(R.id.disease_submit_button)
    public void diseaseSubmit() {
        String cropName = cropET.getText().toString();
        String region = regionET.getText().toString();
        String diseaseDescription = descriptionET.getText().toString();

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cropName) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(region) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(diseaseDescription) && !diseaseType.equals("Select") && !weatherType.equals("Select") && !soilCondition.equals("Select") && !district.equals("Select")) {

            disease.cropName = cropName;
            disease.diseaseType = diseaseType;
            disease.dateTime = time;
            disease.diseaseDescription = diseaseDescription;
            disease.district = district;
            disease.region = region;
            disease.soilCondition = soilCondition;
            disease.weatherType = weatherType;

            // get photos
//            Bitmap photo1BM = ((BitmapDrawable) photo1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
//            String bm1 = BaseActivity.getResizedBitmap(photo1BM, 100, 100);

            File myFile = new File(fileUri.getPath());
            String absolutePath = myFile.getAbsolutePath();

            disease.photo1Path = absolutePath;
//            disease.photo1 = (Multipart) myFile;

            if (NetworkService.isNetWorkAvailable(this)) {
                /*ReportDiseasePostTask userRegisterPostTask = new ReportDiseasePostTask(this, disease, authPreferences.getUserId());
                userRegisterPostTask.execute();*/
                BaseActivity.showProgress(this);
                RetrofitBuilder.getBuilder().create(CommunicationService.class).postDiseaseReport(disease).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                        if (response.isSuccess()) {
                            String result = null;
                            try {
                                result = response.body().string();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String gs = sExposeGson.toJson(result);
                            Log.i("ADMS: ", "response = " + gs + " status: " + response.code());
                            if (result != null && result.toLowerCase().contains("success")) {
                                BaseActivity.hideProgress();
                                Toast.makeText(DiseaseActivity.this, "Disease report saved successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                                startActivity(new Intent(DiseaseActivity.this, DiseaseActivity.class));
                            } else {
                                BaseActivity.hideProgress();
                                Toast.makeText(DiseaseActivity.this, "Problem occurred while saving.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            BaseActivity.hideProgress();
                            Toast.makeText(DiseaseActivity.this, "Problem occurred while saving.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                        BaseActivity.hideProgress();
                        Toast.makeText(DiseaseActivity.this, "Problem occurred while saving.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            } else {
                NetworkService.showNoConnectionDialog(this);
            }

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all the necessary fields before register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

    }
```